# How to throw an error with a try catch exception

Tags: php, pdo

I have a database 'users', where data from the html form is sent, it contains fields, 'name', 'email', 'number' and 'date', the field 'date' is unique, it cannot get two identical values, when I try to send 2 identical values ​​I get the error: "Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE [23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '2021-11-30 00:00:00' for key 'users.date_visit' ".

I need to use a try, catch exception to display this error to the user as a string. Help me how to do it

A function that sends values ​​to the database:

```
public function setData($name, $number, $email, $date)
    {
            $data = [
                'name' => $name,
                'number'=> $number,
                'email' => $email,
                'date' => $date
            ];

            $query = $this->connection->prepare("INSERT INTO Example.users (name, phone_number, email, date_visit)
            values (:name, :number, :email, :date)");

            $query->execute($data);

            return "Information got into the database";
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you read [the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdoexception.php) and try adding a try/catch block?

Comment: I tried so I decided to write here

Comment: Please post what you tried.

Answer (score -1):

the easiest way is to make exception within the `$query`like this

```
public function setData($name, $number, $email, $date)
    {
            $data = [
                'name' => $name,
                'number'=> $number,
                'email' => $email,
                'date' => $date
            ];

            $query = $this->connection->prepare("INSERT INTO Example.users (name, phone_number, email, date_visit) values (:name, :number, :email, :date)");
            
            if(!$query) die ($this->connection->error);
            
            $query->execute($data);

            return "Information got into the database";
    }
}
```

most likely, this will fail. the next step is to add
`$this->connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` to wherever you make the connection call from

then change your code to

```
public function setData($name, $number, $email, $date)
    {
            $data = [
                'name' => $name,
                'number'=> $number,
                'email' => $email,
                'date' => $date
            ];

            try{
                $query = $this->connection->prepare("INSERT INTO Example.users (name, phone_number, email, date_visit) values (:name, :number, :email, :date)");
                $query->execute($data);
                return "Information got into the database";
            }
            catch (PDOException $error)
            {
                return $error->getMessage();
            }
    }
}
```